# Issue in call recording and not supporting in Android 7.0?

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, voice-recording

[image]

Issue is Call recording is working fine upto android version **6.0.1** but it is not working properly above that android version.

**Problem:-** the call is on for 1 minute but recording is stop in 2 to 3 seconds.

Here Edittext of Contact:

```
edt_attempt_contact.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.getX() >= (edt_attempt_contact.getRight() - edt_attempt_contact.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    if (!edt_attempt_contact.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + edt_attempt_contact.getText().toString()));
                        try {
                            startActivity(i);
                        }catch (SecurityException s){
                            s.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            audioRecord();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Attempt Contact Number is required to call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the main code for Call Recording.

```
 private void audioRecord() throws IOException {

    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(root + "/"
            .concat("_")
            .concat(generateUniqueFileName())
            .concat(".amr"));


    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();
}
```

I had taken all need permissions for android recording still it is not working in above android 6.0.1 versions.Thank you in advance for the solutions...

Comment: Please add a more detailed problem description than _"not working properly "_.

Comment: Call is on for 1 minute but the recording is stop immediately in few sec i.e 3 sec in above versions...

Comment: is something to add in this code for version above 6.0.1 ?? @Michael

Comment: `startActivity(i);` if that fails, an exception occurs, and it falls through in attempting `audioRecord();`

Comment: whats the solution @t0mm13b ?

Comment: Use a flag of some sort, set off the flag within the try block after `startActivity(i)` is invoked, further on in the code, if the flag is set then call `audioRecord();` - this will confirm that its a Nougat issue.

Comment: initially flag=0 and flag is 1 if it goes in startactivity(i) yeah it is going in audio record if flag=1. @t0mm13b

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the call recording code in Service or Activity?

The activity fill stop once the call recording is started so if your code is in activity the call recording will stop.

Comment: yaa Call recording is in activity,then why the recording is working well in lollypop versions?

Answer (score 0):

Android 7 doesn't support voice call  use micro

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```